# "401 Unauthorized" while using vss-web-extension-sdk for requests

Tags: javascript, get, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am in the process of creating a report, generated and organized from various VSTS API calls. I am running into a wall using the vss.sdk to make the requests to the git rest api. The request seemed easy enough, following from examples [The Core Client SDK Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk)

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Controls","VSS/Service", "VSS/Controls/TreeView", "TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient"], function(
  VSS_Controls,
  VSS_Service,
  TreeView,
  GitClient){

//...Various Functions are Defined...

module.exports.getRepos = async function(Project){ 
  var client = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(GitClient.GitHttpClient2_1);
  return await client.getRepositories(Project);
}
```

The response I get back is "401: error: TF400813: The user '####MyUserID####' is not authorized to access this resource."

My tests were done on my personal VSTS account where I am an Administrator, so it shouldn't be an issue with my permissions.

Any and all thoughts\suggestions\prayers\ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on the [Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/manifest#scopes) to generate the access token, so check the scopes of your extension (e.g. vso.code_manage)